# How to use Icon fonts

Tags: visual-studio-code, icon-fonts

I just installed Icon fonts from market in VS-Code, but it seems like this extension doesn't work well in my React project, but it does support JSX which has mentioned in the introduction.Here are two main problems:

1. I could use the snippets, but the icon just don't show on the page.
2. There is even no suggestions when I typing on React page whose language mode is babel javascript.

Comment: Have you imported the scripts?

Comment: But it doesn't mention about importing scripts in the market detail page,by the way, could u please tell me what should I imoprt if I do need to do that?

Comment: The extension only provides the snippets for the icons. You have to download/import the icon pack to your project.